# awk sum of selected values in column

Tags: linux, awk

I want to sum selected values in column in `awk`. Second column is time. I want to add values from `4th` column in each second.

Input:

```
1 0.1 2 1 3
2 0.3 2 2 3
4 0.6 2 3 3
2 1.1 2 4 3
5 1.3 2 5 3
6 2.2 2 6 3
7 2.7 2 7 3
8 3.6 2 8 3
9 3.9 2 1 3
10 4.1 2 1 3
```

Expected output (we have `5` seconds):

```
6
9
13
9
1
```

EDIT:

Here is my `code` but i have no idea how can it works dynamic.

```
awk '$2>x && $2<=y (sum+=$4) END {print sum}' filename
```

where `x` - start time, `y` - end time. It works only for static values, it means that now I can obtain result only for one selected second.

Comment: Welcome to SO, always try to wrap your samples in code tags `{}` button and try to produce simple samples(which you have done now) too so that it will be easy to understand for people, cheers and happy learning on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following `awk` program

```
BEGIN {
    total = 0
    secondEnd = 1
}
{
    if($2 < secondEnd) {
        total += $4
        next
    }

    while($2 > secondEnd) {
        print(total)
        total = 0
        secondEnd++
    }
    total = $4
}
END {
    print(total)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

***EDIT:*** As per OP's request adding a code which will accept any field provided to it as a `awk` variable.

```
awk -v col1="2"  -F"[ .]" '$col1 == prev+1{print sum;sum=prev=""} {sum+=$NF;prev=$col1} END{if(prev && sum){print sum}}' Input_file
```

OR(a non-one liner form of solution here)

```
awk -v col1="2"  -F"[ .]" '
$col1 == prev+1{
  print sum;
  sum=prev=""
}
{
  sum+=$NF;
  prev=$col1
}
END{
  if(prev && sum){
    print sum}
}'  Input_file
```

In case you are passing a bash variable to `awk` variable then do following.

```
column=2 ##Shell variable
awk -v col1="$column"  -F"[ .]" '$col1 == prev+1{print sum;sum=prev=""} {sum+=$NF;prev=$col1} END{if(prev && sum){print sum}}' Input_file
```

---

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps you(considering that your actual Input_file is same as shown sample here).

```
awk -F"[ .]" '$2 == prev+1{print sum;sum=prev=""} {sum+=$NF;prev=$2} END{if(prev && sum){print sum}}'  Input_file
```

Adding a non-one liner form of solution too now.

```
awk -F"[ .]" '
$2 == prev+1{
  print sum;
  sum=prev=""
}
{
  sum+=$NF;
  prev=$2
}
END{
  if(prev && sum){
    print sum}
}'  Input_file
```

Comment: Thank you. It works almost perfectly. Could you modified code in order to choose specific column?

Comment: If I have 5 column, it does not work in general. But it works if I use expression NF-1 (for fourth column). Could you modify a code in order to work for selected column, for example $4.

Comment: @k.tygrys, try to give samples which are near to requirement because solutions will be given as per those only.  I did that check my EDIT solution and let me know then?

Comment: I have added one column and it works with NF-1 only but i would like to select suitable column e.g. $4. Please look on the updated post.